# Set OnClickListener on Buttons in an ArrayList (Button number unknown)

Tags: android, button

I'm developing a Web browser, and I'm storing the "tabs" (`Button`s) in an `ArrayList`, for easy use. How do I set the `OnClickListener` on every button? The buttons have to start an `Intent`. Here's my code so far:

```
public class OpenTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 
 private LinearLayout buttons;
 private int tabno = -1;
 private Intent in;
 private Intent settings;
 private ArrayList<Button> list;
 private Button newTab;
 private Context ctx;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_tabs);
     setSupportActionBar((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
     buttons = findViewById(R.id.scroll_linear);
     in = new Intent();
     settings = new Intent();
     list = new ArrayList<Button>();
     newTab = findViewById(R.id.newtab);
     ctx = this;

     newTab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Button n = new Button(ctx);
             list.add(n);
             tabno += 1;
             Button nB = list.get(tabno);
             nB.setText(getText(R.string.newtab));
             // nB.id = tabno
             buttons.addView(nB);
         }
     });
 }
// ...
}
```

Comment: What should button give you return? when it is clicked?

Comment: Edited (The buttons have to start an Intent)

Comment: and where intents stored?

Comment: I was thinking like

    `for(Button btn in list) {
      btn.setOnClickListener(/*...*/)
    }`

Comment: I mean how will you differentiate between which button is clicked, and what data will you pass to next activity that will create a difference

Comment: Like: `in.putExtra("tabno", list.indexOf(btn))`

Comment: Then you can use for loop like you said.

Comment: You need to set Listener inside loop . Thats the only way if you use `addView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a single OnClickListener to avoid wasting memory creating and binding different instances of the same object.

Then, as suggested by comments, you must set it with a for, like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_tabs);
    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
    buttons = findViewById(R.id.scroll_linear);
    in = new Intent();
    settings = new Intent();
    list = new ArrayList<Button>();
    newTab = findViewById(R.id.newtab);
    ctx = this;

     View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            switch (v.getId()) {
                case 1:
                    // do something
                    break;

                case 2:
                    // do something
                    break;

                default:
                    // do something
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    for (Button b : list) {
        b.setOnClickListener(listener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Button btn : list){
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
} });
}
```